# MySQL database responding strangely to update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am using a MySQL db, when i run the below script it behaves very strangely. the current behaviour is...

if password is something normal it changes password to 0 but ignores the token value.

if the password is already 0 it just runs, doesn't do anything, and says 0 rows affected.

If someone could give me a clue as to why this is happening that would be great. My SQL is...

```
UPDATE travisor_tradesperson SET password='123456789' AND token = '' WHERE email='rhamilton469@qub.ac.uk'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. You separate columns in the `set` clause with a comma (`,`), not with (`and`):

```
UPDATE travisor_tradesperson 
SET    password = '123456789', token = ''
-- Here ---------------------^
WHERE  email='rhamilton469@qub.ac.uk'
```

Answer (score 3):

As to *why does it do that*, since you had the syntax wrong (as per other answer), the whole part after `SET`

```
password='123456789' AND token = ''
```

was probably interpreted as a single assignment of `'123456789' AND token = ''` into `password`. This was likely understood by MySQL as applying an boolean AND on a string converted to boolean and the result of the comparison `token = ''`.

Answer (score 2):

Use commas to separate column and is an operator which for conditional statement, we can use it after where clause.

```
UPDATE travisor_tradesperson 
SET    password = '123456789', token = 'xyz' 
WHERE  email='rhamilton469@qub.ac.uk'
```